# How do I add veneer stone to an exterior painted wall?

Tags: concrete

I have an exterior painted wall and am interested in installing a stone veneer. I realize that I may have to install wire mesh to the areas but I'm wondering if there is a material that can be used to apply to the stone to the painted wall without mesh? Or should the paint be removed as much as possible then attach the wire mesh and apply a scratch coat?

Comment: What is the surface of the wall (under the paint) made of?

Comment: Before you can tell if you need to put something up over it, we really need to know what the wall's made out of. There's a chance you need to completely remove what's there now if it's something like EIFS or T-111, because no wire mesh will support a stone veneer applied to an inadequate substrate.

Answer (score 3):

You need mesh. While veneer is a fraction of the weight of full stone, it is not light. The mesh forms a framework that the bonding material will surround and be inseparable from it (absent smashing with a hammer). The mesh is firmly attached to the underlying structure with fasteners (type depending on the nature of the siding).

In this case, the painting of the surface makes no difference.

Getting mortar to adhere directly to an existing concrete, stucco, brick or stone surface is not simple, especially when there is a tendency of the attached material to pull away from that surface. Adding to a horizontal surface (like a concrete floor, steps or walk), there is mostly a compression force (pushing the surfaces together), and bonding makes more sense. On a vertical (or overhead) surface, where the force is tension (pulling away), this makes less sense.

I think you need the mesh.

Comment: Agreed. While you could strip the entire wall, and then use a bonding agent, I'd still prefer to trust mesh that is physically attached to the wall. As such, I wouldn't even bother with removing the paint and put the money and time towards getting the mesh and anchors correct first.

Answer (score 1):

If your substrate is CMU or concrete then you can sandblast it, remove the residue and install stone veneer with a polymer modified mortar or thinset. If it's any other material you'll need to install a weather resistant barrier, metal lath and a scratch coat before installing manufactured stone (no need to sandblast if this is the case). Here's a website with more [stone installation techniques](http://www.coronado.com).

Answer (score 0):

A sand blaster is your tool of choice for removing the paint and leaving a good surface for the mortar to stick to.

Do note that one purpose of the mesh is to help hold the mortar in place while it sets up. It also helps to prevent future cracks from shifting.

Answer (score 0):

i did my fire place  it was  brick that had been painted , so being an engineer i did  a test and took one rock veneer  used liquid nails let it set up for a few days then came back  took a chair and stood next to it and put my full 240 lbs of body weight on it and it didnt budge  i decided i had  enough evidence it was safe to procede . i have a fine looking fire place i also grouted the 5/8 gaps between the stones, i  think this is an excellent method .